# Jquery not working in IE

Tags: jquery

could some one look as this Jquery code, I am trying to make a Ajax plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#letter-a a').click(function() {
  $('#dictionary').load('a.php') ;
  return false;
  });
});
```

Basically it wont work in IE , In FF and Safari it works perfect.

Comment: also, define "won't work" - does the click event not fire? does the load() not load the content? does it give an error?

Comment: It'd be easier for people to help if, instead of just telling us what it "basically" does, you would describe exactly what it does, and what you've learned in any attempts to debug the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess, because not enough info is given. IE is in general more strict with the content type of Ajax loaded html. Make sure that a.php is actually returning text/html.

Also, if you are building a framework, it would be better to use the more powerful $.ajax method. Among others it allows you to register a callback in case of an error. This could be handy in your situation.

Comment: error handler I use to debug errors with $.ajax.  Make a div on your page with id="debug".
error: function(xhr){ alert('Error processing request');$('#debug').html(xhr.responseText); },

Answer (score 0):

1, I guess this is a problem of loading the same DIVs recursively into itself? You load into #dictionary .. but the outer div of the returned code is a #dictionary, Check that out

2, I would also try to put your link as **a href="javascript:void(0)"** and remove the return false..

3, Maybe it's also that a.php returns a full page with the `<html>` tag, a.php only need to return a portion of HTML

4, Check for HTML/XHTML validity, it's surprising how it can affect the behavior

Thank